# differential equations/ linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

[image]

Hello! I know this is not a platform for homework to be answered, but I am working on a test review sheet for my differential equations class and I am pretty desperate for help with this question. I am extremely lost, to the point where I don't know how to even begin this problem, so if someone could help me answer it I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17164/suggested-guideline-for-i-dont-know-where-to-begin-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tell what you have to do:

- items a) and c) will go almost at once. Since $\dim \Bbb R^3 = 3$, and you have three vectors, is suffices to see that they are linearly independent. If they are, they form a basis. Look at the determinant: $$\begin{vmatrix} -1 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & 5 & 1 \\ 3 & 1 & 0\end{vmatrix}$$
  If it is zero, then the vectors lie in a plane, hence they are linearly dependent. If the determinant in non zero, its absolute value is the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors.
- for item b), recall that if $\theta = \angle({\bf v},{\bf w})$, then: $$\cos \theta = \frac{\langle {\bf v},{\bf w}\rangle}{\|{\bf v}\|\|{\bf w}\|},$$ you just have to use the formula twice.
- for item d), write $${\bf u} = a{\bf e}_1+ b{\bf e}_2 + c{\bf e}_3,$$ and make the components equal. You will get a $3 \times 3$ system on $a,b$ and $c$, which you can solve anyway you like.

Now it's on you!

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! I understand how to go about this problem now and I was able to successfully answer it. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me!

Comment: Glad to help! ${}$